# How to properly convert SQL image data type into Postgres image data type(bytea)

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

When I convert an image data type in SQL server to Postgres it initially looks like this in SQL Server (see bytes column):

[image: SQL Server]

I run the conversion using the following SQL statements as an example(see line 3):

[image: SQL Statements]

But when I take a look at the way the data is stored in my Postgres database it does not look like the way it was stored in SQL Server it looks totally different. I also can't render it. See below for how it looks (see the bytes column):

[image: Postgres Database]

My question is how do I properly convert it in my sql statement before I import it into postgres so it can be read as an image?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on PostgreSQL bytes type literals (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-binary.html)? Excerpt "The "hex" format encodes binary data as 2 hexadecimal digits per byte, most significant nibble first. The entire string is preceded by the sequence \x".

Comment: I see that I think I am just confused as to how to get that to convert over through the postgres console.

Comment: Please stop reposting variants of this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45608017/398670, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45602818/398670 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I render in my rails app a bytea image from postgres which was converted from SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608017/how-do-i-render-in-my-rails-app-a-bytea-image-from-postgres-which-was-converted)